# How to use \resizebox for an alignment of equations with one tag for the last one

Tags: align, boxes, resize, tags

Does anyone know how I can use `\resizebox` for an alignment of equations? Currently, I use `\split` instead or `\align`, because I don't know how to use `\align` in combination with `\resizebox`. The problem with `\split`, however, is that the `\tag` refers to the whole `\equation`. I need it to refer to the last row only.

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{$ \begin{split}
    NOJDIAFSYZ&=\frac{bhisaofhbpüghidrpbgnnbjhioboasbuobovbihbjkdbkjs}{njofnpvybnjdpojnvodynbonoboy} \\
    \Leftrightarrow nbjosdbfoUERSGBN &= nojasgvbnajuorbuvjoybujorgjbolbydozugh  \\
    \Leftrightarrow \qquad \qquad \quad \ njbsoibvos &= bosjbvojoydbkbufbkcbjbuujdbkivbjydjkbhvrfbiykbvhk. 
    \end{split}$}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[image]

I'd be very grateful for helping comments! :)

Comment: are you sure you want to use `\resizebox` on equations (or any text at all) it will always cause inconsistent font sizes and a rather odd looking document. but if you want to have any display material inside resizebox (or fbox or mbox, etc) use `\resizebox{..}{..}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{align}.....`

Comment: If you give an example document, please make sure it is a **working**  document.

Comment: Well, I know it looks bad, but I don't have any better ideas. The equations are just way too long. \footnotesize is not enough.

Answer (score 6):

You can make the equation smaller by selecting a smaller font, e.g. `\small` or `\footnotesize`. Then you can use `align`.

And it is better to let `align` do the alignment than to use manual spacing with `\quad` and `\`. That is prone to errors.
For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

  \begin{footnotesize}
    \begin{align}
      && NOJDIAFSYZ &=\frac{\mathit{bhisaofhbpüghidrpbgnnbjhioboasbuobovbihbjkdbkjs}}{njofnpvybnjdpojnvodynbonoboy} \notag\\
    \Leftrightarrow && nbjosdbfoUERSGBN &= nojasgvbnajuorbuvjoybujorgjbolbydozugh  \notag\\
    \Leftrightarrow && njbsoibvos &= \textit{bosjbvojoydbkbufbkcbjbuujdbkivbjydjkbhvrfbiykbvhk}. 
    \end{align}
  \end{footnotesize}

  \begin{small}
    \begin{align}
      && NOJDIAFSYZ &=\frac{\mathit{bhisaofhbpüghidrpbgnnbjhioboasbuobovbihbjkdbkjs}}{njofnpvybnjdpojnvodynbonoboy} \notag\\
    \Leftrightarrow && nbjosdbfoUERSGBN &= nojasgvbnajuorbuvjoybujorgjbolbydozugh  \notag\\
    \Leftrightarrow && njbsoibvos &= \textit{bosjbvojoydbkbufbkcbjbuujdbkivbjydjkbhvrfbiykbvhk}. 
    \end{align}
  \end{small}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suppose these long "identifiers" are just filler text; otherwise you should put then in `\mathit` or `\mathrm` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on \quad, I don't know that \align can match more than one &. I've already tried \footnotesize, it is not small enough. And yes, of course that's just filler text :)

Comment: align can have 2n-1 `&`'s for n columns. Usually you use that for a number of equations in a row, one & inside each equation (which consists of 2 columns), often before the `=` sign, and one between equations. The alignment of the columns is RLRL...

Comment: Did you try with text on several lines before the display?

Answer (score 1):

I used `matrix` instead of `split` to determine the width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{showframe}%MWE only

\NewEnviron{resizealign}{\sbox0{\let\notag=\relax
    $\begin{matrix}\displaystyle\BODY\end{matrix}$}%
  \sbox1{$(\theequation)$}%
  \sbox2{\parbox{\dimexpr \wd0 + 2\wd1}%
    {\begin{align}\BODY\end{align}}}% for testing
  \noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{resizealign}
    NOJDIAFSYZ&=\frac{bhisaofhbpüghidrpbgnnbjhioboasbuobovbihbjkdbkjs}{njofnpvybnjdpojnvodynbonoboy} \notag\\
    \Leftrightarrow nbjosdbfoUERSGBN &= nojasgvbnajuorbuvjoybujorgjbolbydozugh  \notag\\
    \Leftrightarrow \qquad \qquad \quad \ njbsoibvos &= bosjbvojoydbkbufbkcbjbuujdbkivbjydjkbhvrfbiykbvhk. 
\end{resizealign}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I just hope it doesn't look too odd in the end, as @David suspects.

Comment: I should mention that matrix adds an extra \arraycolsep to the width.  OTOH, one cannot predict precisely how wide the equation numbers are going to be, so a little extra space is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation number below the last equation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 && 
 NOJDIAFSYZ&=\frac{bhisaofhbpüghidrpbgnnbjhioboasbuobovbihbjkdbkjs}{njofnpvybnjdpojnvodynbonoboy
  \nonumber}\\
\Leftrightarrow && nbjosdbfoUERSGBN &= nojasgvbnajuorbuvjoybujorgjbolbydozugh  \nonumber\\
\Leftrightarrow && njbsoibvos       &= 
        osjbvojoydbkbufbkcbjbuujdbkivbjydjkbhvrfbiykbvhk. 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```